# How To Make Filtered List More Dynamic In Vue

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuex

So I have a list of items that I am looping through using `v-for`. Before the list is printed it is filtered by a value using the `.filter()` method. Also to change between filtered values I am using `v-on:click`. My question is, is there a way I could make the filter more dynamic? because if the predefined values I have set to filter the list are changed then the filter will no longer work...

I have provided a JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/boldstar/eywraw8t/435505/) So you could see what it is that I am working with.

My 2 main areas of concern are the `v-on` and computed methods..

```
<li class="d-flex justify-content-between" v-on:click="engagementFilterKey = 'recieved'">
     <div class="ml-3">
     <span class="text-muted">Received</span>
     </div>
</li>
<li class="d-flex justify-content-between" v-on:click="engagementFilterKey = 'preparation'">
     <div class="ml-3">
     <span class="text-muted">Preparation</span>
     </div>
</li>
```

Here is the computed methods

```
computed: {
    engagementFilter() {
      return this[this.engagementFilterKey];
    },
    recieved() {
        return this.allEngagements.filter((engagement) => engagement.status == 'Recieved')
    },
    preparation() {
        return this.allEngagements.filter((engagement) => engagement.status == 'Preparation')
    },
```

Please view the fiddle I posted at the top of this discussion...

Comment: Do you mean you want to handle any status as a filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated**

Idea is to create unique set of statuses from an array of engagements and dynamically render list of buttons. Each button will assign `engagementFilterKey` which can be used to filter out matching statuses from the list of all engagements.

Solution code - [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aBiscuit/uzqg40rn/9/)

Comment: the method works great, however I have 2 issues. The order in which the statuses are listed is random and im not sure there is a way to fix that. The other is when the page first loads there is no list. I have to click before the filtered list appeared. Originally it was using the `engagementFilterKey` to show the first selected filter. Am I missing something?

Comment: I've updated JSFiddle, to hide the list initially, by setting empty string value for initial filter key: `engagementFilterKey: ''`. As for order requirement, you have an array of statuses. There are plenty ways to arrange these values. They can be ordered by number of objects of certain status in the list, names, etc.. If you want to have a custom order, it surely can be done. But for that an order schema definition is required. For example, a list of all available values based which new array should be sorted.

Comment: I wish it was as simple as alphabetical, however I would like it in the order of workflow that the status represents. for example, the list should be `received`, `scanned`, `preparation`, `review`, `complete`. So by "certain status" would be ideal if that is possible... The other option is that I manipulate that data in such a way from my backend that allows for it to be ordered a certain on the front end maybe?

Comment: Please, check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aBiscuit/uzqg40rn/15/) for custom ordered version :) You can setup an array in which order you want statuses to be sorted.

Comment: Awesome, thanks @aBiscuit, I have one more issue, and that is how can I apply your `mapOrder` function into my vue project. I see that it cannot be used in my `methods` or `computed` areas. Do I have to put it in main.js file?

Comment: This kind of functions are called "helpers" or "utils". It is a good practice to create a separate folder, let's say `utils` inside `src` folder with `index.js` file exporting all reusable functions (e.g. `export function mapOrder (array, order) { ... }`  and import that function on demand into components, which will look like this: `import { mapOrder } from '@/utils' (if you have '@' alias setup)

Comment: okay so I have created the separate file and imported into my component and it appears that I am getting an alarm saying that `cannot read property "indexOf" of undefined`?

Comment: @TJWeems aBiscuit is going out of his way to help you. Stackoverflow isn't a coding service and these questions are well beyond the scope of the original question. You should upvote and accept and ask additional questions if you have follow ups or start a chat room if aBiscuit is willing to continue.

Comment: @aBiscuit I figured it out. Your solution works. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @Bert also thanks for your help. I'm learning. I ask a lot of questions. But dully noted.